# Error saving a document as PDF using SageMath in Cocalc

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation

I need to save a .ipynb file I have created in Cocalc (using SageMath 9.6), but whenever I try to save it, I get the following message:

```
Running nbconvert failed with an error 6 minutes ago. Read the error log below, update you Jupyter notebook, then try it again.
   killed command 'bash /tmp/cocalc-NfH7tU/a.sh'
```

I tried to save it as PDF via JupyterLab nbconvert and Chrome or via Classic nbconvert and Chrome but I get the same message of error.

Could this be solved?